# How to transfer props together with router-link

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vue-router, vue-router4

I will try to describe it briefly. I have the data about the ads received through the request. This is an array of objects containing the name, picture, price, and so on. To draw them, there is a component that accepts props :

```
export default {
  name: "AnnounsmentItem",
  props: {
    announsment: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
```

This object (props) is passed there using v-for from another page:

```
<AnnounsmentItem
          v-for="announsment in announsments.data"
          :key="announsment.id"
          :announsment="announsment"
        ></AnnounsmentItem>
```

Now I have decided that for each ad I need a separate page that will open by clicking on the button inside the card (the first code). Here's how I implemented:

```
<router-link
            :to="{
              path: '/announsment/' + announsment.id,
              params: {
                announsment: announsment,
              },
            }"
            class="text-decoration-none link-primary"
            :announsment="announsment"
            >{{ this.announsment.title }}</router-link
          >
```

This all happens in the body of the first component. The cards are displayed normally, but when you try to click on the button in them (which should send ads to the page). The address is transferred, but does not come out due to the fact that there are no received details. Here's what the console writes:
[Vue Router Warning]: The path "/ad/12" was passed with parameters, but they will be ignored. Instead, use a named route next to the parameters.
And now the most important question. Can I somehow transfer props to the ad page rendering component with the current implementation, or do I need to do something differently, and if so, what?

The console suggests that I use named paths, but I do not know how to implement this with the inclusion of a variable in the path.
I know that there are already similar questions on StackOverflow, but they either do not answer my problem, or about something else, namely about the transfer of a composite address

router code:

```
{
    path: "/announsment/:id",
    name: "aboba",
    component: AnnounsmentPage,
    props: true,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `props: true` in your route, in that case the router will pass the router parameters  as props to the route's component.
Other options related to `props` are here:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html
*RYFM* :)

Comment: I have this property enabled, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @wstr27 you didn't provide your router code...

Comment: Yes, I forgot, I'll fix it now